# Python Moving between rooms with a Dictions

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I'm working on a coding project for class, which requires the user to be able to move between rooms. I'm having an issue with one specific part of the code. I can't figure out how to pull the room name from the dictionary. I can get the rest to work. The line I need help with is "('You are in the {}.'.format(player_room[]))". Here is my code:

```
rooms = {
    'Great Hall': {'South': 'Bedroom'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Great Hall', 'East': 'Cellar'},
    'Cellar': {'West': 'Bedroom'}
}

while player_move != 'Exit':
if player_move in moves:
if player_move in player_room:
   player_room = rooms[player_room[player_move]]
   print('You are in the {}.'.format(player_room[]))
   print('Enter a move:')
   player_move = input()
 elif player_move not in player_room:
    print('Invalid move.')
    print('Enter a move:')
    player_move = input()
```

Comment: You need to have one variable where you store the room the player is currently in.  I'm not sure what you are storing in `player_room`, but it doesn't appear to be what you need.

Comment: what are `moves`?

Comment: I think you just need to remove the `[]` after the `player_room` in `format` and the printing should work fine.

Comment: Please make sure that your indentation is correct - in Python indents are relevant to the syntax. The way you formatted your script in the question is not valid making it more difficult to answer your question.